# Is it possible to use regfree COM from registered COM?

Tags: com, regfreecom, winsxs

I've been trying to implement following scenario:

Application [C++] uses CoCreateInstance on registered COM class (CReg/Reg.dll)

CReg class uses CoCreateInstance on regfree/SxS COM class (CFree/Free.dll).

CoCreateInstance returns REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG.

Problem doesn't seem to be with manifests, because if I try to instantiate CFree directly via application, object is created with no problem.

I have checked and scenario above triggers Activation Context of CReg (I have checked with sxstrace) and even manifest of the CFree is loaded successfully (!) which should effect in correct regfree COM. If I change manifest of the CFree then Activation Contexts fails (which I believe is proof for me that it was correctly triggered and loaded before the change).

Is scenario with using registered COM [CReg] not possible to access CFree object? If it is possible, are there some special work in order to load it properly?

**EDIT**

With Joe's help, we worked out that the problem is where Free.dll is located.

Main application is (for example) in C:\Proj\App, both Reg.dll and Free.dll are in C:\Proj\Libs. Is there possibility to load regfree Free.dll which is in different location than application? Problem is that I can't place it in application directory or in application child directory (it has to be in external location).

I have tried to use ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED preprocessor definition on Reg.dll project, to trigger Activation context from Reg.dll directory. Manifest from Free.dll is loaded properly (sxstrace logs that) but CoCreateInstance call is still returning REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. [This blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2007/06/26/rt_manifest-resource-and-isolation_aware_enabled/) points that it may be possible with this definition (but is not giving definite answer on this matter).

Anyone can help me solve this problem or at least point to the documentation that may give me an answer, whether it is possible or not, to load regfree dll from an external location?

Comment: Are they all in the same directory?

Comment: In the scenario with registered COM, application is in (let's say) C:\Proj\App\ directory and in C:\Proj\Libs\ is Free.dll and Reg.dll. In case of direct dependency of application on Free.dll, these are in same directory.

Comment: My first step in troubleshooting would be 1) Make sure all works with normal registered COM for both DLLs.  2) Make sure all works with both DLLs registration free, 3) try making one registered and one not.  The manifests work on relative paths where all of the reg free COM stuff has to be in the directory or sub-directory of the process.  I would try moving the Reg.dll to the same directory as the other two files, and registering it there.

Comment: I have found out that registered COM component (Reg.dll) is loading properly CFree object, but only when Free.dll is in directory where application is (Reg.dll is still in C:\Proj\Libs,). I am not sure what to think about it since sxstrace was showing that manifest of Free.dll was loaded properly (when it still was in C:\Proj\Libs). My initial question is somehow answered now, but that does not solve my problem. That Reg.dll component have to use Free.dll and has to be in same directory (these can't be in app's dir). Linking it with Reg.dll or registering Free.dll is not solving my problem.

Comment: I had a feeling it was because they weren't all in the same directory.  Registration free COM is something that is directory centric and an installation can sometimes be thought of just doing an xcopy of files--overly simplistic I know.  From the EXE you can call CoGetClassObject().  You could add a member to your CReg object that received a IClassFactory* interface so that you could try working around the limitations of being or not being in the same directory.

Comment: So, it is not possible to load regfree library from other than application dir or application child dir? I tried to use manifest with relative path like "..\Libs" but it failed every time (same with absolute path). I just thought that with ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED macro, created activation context and manifests are probed on base of dll directory. This would let me overcome the barrier of having library only in application directory. Sxstrace showed that activation context was looking for manifests, not libraries in Reg dir. It would be good to inform about not loaded dll, though.

Comment: My experience has been it is only possible for same directory or for child directories.  I have failed trying to use relative paths that were not in child directories.  If I could direct you to some documentation, I would.  Just going off of my experience.  You could also rely on other trickery.  You could make your EXE always load the free.dll and have the DllMain() of that library register a class factory as running.  Then, CReg would pick it up.  Or you could pass the class factory around...

Comment: I will edit my question to be more specific about the issue, maybe someone else knows the answer. Documentation... I know that pain. I tried to work my way out using it. Effect is the post on Stack :P. Yet, I feel that I will ask you (in near future) to post your comments as an answer and I will accept it. This may be hopeless issue. Thanks for help. though :)

Comment: It seems like there is no point to keep that question unanswered. Joe, post your answer, maybe also with suggestion on IClassFactory lookup. I will accept it.